# Re-enabling GIT control in copied project, in a new branch

Tags: git

A friend sent me a zip file with an XCode workspace.
I opened the project and changed a lot of files.
Now, my friend says to me "Please, commit your changes in my BeanStalk repo in a new branch."

How can I do this?

I suppose to need a checkout and commit, like this:

```
git checkout -b <new-branch>
git commit
```

Answer (score 3):

First, tell your friend not to go sending out zip files if they expect people to be branching their repo.

Then you need to clone their repository, it will be something like:

```
git clone https://accountname.git.beanstalkapp.com/gitreponame.git 
cd gitreponame
```

Then create a branch:

```
git checkout -b <branch_name>
```

If you want to commit everything as one giant change (not ideal but maybe all you want in this case), copy all of your changes in to the repo. Then add and commit them:

```
git commit -am"<commit message>"
```

Then push them back up to your friend's repo:

```
git push -u origin <branch name>
```

But really, you're going to want to start reading up on git if you're going to be contributing. There are a lot of ways to go wrong if you don't know what you're doing. There are a lot of tutorials online.

Comment: hurray for the first line!

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

1. Check out his code (`git checkout master`) to an empy folder in your file system
2. Make new branch (`git checkout -b my-new-branch`)
3. Manually replace the files with your version (e.g using Total Commander)
4. Stage changes and Commit

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, **clone the repository**:

```
git clone <git-path>
```

(Alternatively you can **initialize an empty repository with `git init`** and add the origin to your target repository with `git origin add ...`, but it's unlikely this will do what you need.)

After getting the repository set up, **make the changes**. The changes will be reflected in `git status`, and you can commit them by the following:

```
git commit --interactive
```

After that, create a new branch at **HEAD**:

```
git checkout -b <branch>
```

Then push them upstream.

```
git push <origin> <branch>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use a GUI client for git if you are new. Things will make more sense because you will see more visually what the options are and what the commands do.

If you are on Mac or Windows you can use SourceTree. If you are on Linux I like to use git-cola. There are plenty to choose from.

Here are the steps you would want to take to push your changes to your friends repository:

1) Check out the branch from the remote repository to your local repository.

2) Create a new branch from the one you checked out

3) Apply the changes to your new branch

4) Stage your changes.

5) Commit your changes to your local repository.

6) Push the changes to your local branch to the remote repository.

Git can seem a little tricky at first so I highly recommend walking through some how-to videos and tutorials, for example: https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1